# Integrating Camunda webapps in spring framework

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, camunda

I setup Camunda in my Spring 3 project (Tomcat server) using this [guide](https://docs.camunda.org/get-started/spring/). I embedded the workflow engine in my project.

However, I cannot access the cockpit when I go to the url http://localhost:8080/camunda/app/. I get a 404 error.

I see that there is a dependency to be added in case of Spring boot according to this [guide](https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.15/user-guide/spring-boot-integration/webapps/)

But I see no such dependencies available for Spring. Do we not get access to webapps while integrating Camunda with Spring?

Also asked this question in the camunda form: https://forum.camunda.org/t/integrating-camunda-webapps-in-spring-framework/27661

Answer (score 0):

You'll need the following dependency.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.camunda.bpm.webapp</groupId>
  <artifactId>camunda-webapp-webjar</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Then ensure you have the required configurations. Refer the spring boot auto configuration set up [here](https://github.com/camunda/camunda-bpm-spring-boot-starter/blob/master/starter-webapp-core/src/main/java/org/camunda/bpm/spring/boot/starter/webapp/CamundaBpmWebappAutoConfiguration.java) and the web app initialiser [here](https://github.com/camunda/camunda-bpm-spring-boot-starter/blob/master/starter-webapp-core/src/main/java/org/camunda/bpm/spring/boot/starter/webapp/CamundaBpmWebappInitializer.java).

Comment: Adding the dependency did not work. How do I infer the configurations from those files you referred to.